# How to change language in bootstrap DateTimePicker with java

Tags: java, gwt, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've searched for a while but I can't figure out how to change the language of the bootstrap DateTimePicker widget in my java gwt web application.
So far I've found that there is a method called setLanguage() which requires a DateTimePickerLanguage parameter but I can't understand how to use it.
I've tried something like this:

```
DateTimePickerLanguage language;
datePicker.setLanguage(language);
```

But it doesn't work because language is not initialized. But how?
Can anyone tell me why there is so little documentation about Bootstrap usage with java and gwt? I mean, there are tons of papers with clear examples about using Bootstrap with html, but none about java and gwt. Thanks.

Comment: Where do I have to add it? DateTimePickerLanguage is an ENUM class.

Comment: Ah then you probably have to choose one of the languages defined in the enumeration. If you are using an IDE you might just be able to type DateTimePickerLanguage. and see all the possibilities.

Comment: My country code is IT but I can't understand how can I set this value for language. It seems impossible.

Comment: something like datePicker.setLanguage(DateTimePickerLanguage.Russian); or ....RU);

Comment: Thanks! It works like this:  
datePicker.setLanguage(DateTimePickerLanguage.IT);

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't get that IT is your language because I was reading IT as Information Technology :)

Comment: Ahaha no problem! If you want you can insert your comment as an answer then I'll accept it.